# Webpack - Include jquery as a plugin for specific pack file only

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I'm using Ruby on Rails 6 with Webpacker. In my packs folder, I have two folders, `frontend` and `admin`. Each folder contains an `application.js` file so each folder appears as `javascript/packs/frontend/application.js` and `javascript/packs/admin/application.js`.

In my `application.html.erb` file for my specific layout, I load `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'frontend/application' %> or` <%= javascript_pack_tag 'admin/application' %>`depending on the layout (frontend or admin). I have recently removed all jQuery code from the code referenced by the`frontend` pack. However, I haven't been able to successfully remove jQuery itself from the frontend; I still need jQuery for the admin pack.

In my `config/webpack/environment.js` file I have the following contents:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Rails: ["@rails/ujs"],
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}))

module.exports = environment
```

This is the code that loads jQuery into all of my packs but I don't know how to force this to load jQuery into just the admin pack.

Comment: `Tree shaking` could automatically do that based on your file inclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jQuery part from `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Rails: ["@rails/ujs"],
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}))
```

And require jQuery manually within the packs where you want it (e.g. `app/javascript/packs/admin.js`):

```
// Require jQuery
global.$ = require("jquery")
```

You'll need to adjust the instances where you call `jQuery` to `$`, otherwise you'll get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` errors.